# drush language importing untranslated strings

Tags: drush, i18n-l10n

I am having 2 environments. A staging and a production one. I want all string to sync the strings, so that whenever a new string comes to staging it is available for translation in production. For this reason I've used [drush_language](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_language) module.

Export via

`drush language-export-translations --statuses='not-translated'`

This provides a .po file where part of it you can see:

```
msgctxt "tripping_context"
msgid "Giannis test translations"
msgstr ""
```

When i run an import on prod via

```
drush language-import-translations  --langcode="sv"
```

No new strings are picked up.

Anything wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 0):

The statuses flag is saying to export untranslated strings, so you are importing an empty file. 
Or are there any steps you missed to describe?